# Selenium execute_script adding "AI" to function

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I've selected a search button:

```
<input type="button" name="Submit" value="Submit" 
onclick="FnAddSearchParameters();" class="myButton rightButton buttonGroup">
```

Using the chrome driver, I've been trying to click the button, to no avail. The regular `button.click()` function only highlights the button, but does not complete the onclick action.

using `execute_script("FnAddSearchParameters();")` I get the error statement

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: 
Message: unknown error: window.opener.FnAddAISearchParameters is not a function
```

Any thoughts on why `AI` being added to the function call? Is there a way around this?

Comment: are you sure you select your button correctly? show code you used

Comment: `button = driver.find_element_by_name("Submit")` I've checked the source, this is the only thing on the page named Submit. As well, the button has a blue rectangular highlight after I use the `button.click()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you are executing wrong using `execute_script`, you should try as below :-

```
button = driver.find_element_by_name("Submit")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", button)
```